# PHP - preg_replace() " to ' between ""

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

Replace " to ' beteween "":
My problem is in json_decode, the database that creates this json
Example:

```
{"LOGRADOURO":"Joana D"Arc",
 "NUMERO":"257",
 "COMPLEMENTO":"",
 "BAIRRO":"barreiro"}
```

to

```
{"LOGRADOURO":"Joana D'Arc",
 "NUMERO":"257",
 "COMPLEMENTO":"",
 "BAIRRO":"barreiro"}
```

I really need a preg_replace, like this:
$return = preg_replace ('/ ("+)" ("+) /'," $1"$2", $return);

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Use a decent method of generating JSON instead? [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is very useful for this.

Comment: @JohnConde Did you see the [meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic) on WHYT? I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/nojk/5214636) that I think is more appropriate. Thoughts?

Comment: @Polish Prince. Thanks for pointing that out. I like your improved comment. Friendly and more informative. I will use that going forward.

Comment: This problem occurred because the data comes from bd

Comment: And my question is how to build a regex to find an " inside two "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the idea, we can't replace all the double quotes, so i though to make a kind of blacklist. Double quotes preceded with `:{,` should not be replaced, the same goes for what come after the double quotes `:},`. I had to remove the newlines/spaces in order for this to work:

```
$json = '{"LOGRADOURO":"Joana D"Arc",
 "NUMERO":"257",
 "COMPLEMENTO":"",
 "BAIRRO":"barreiro"}';

$json = preg_replace(
array('/",[\s\r\n]+"/',          '/([^\:\{\,])(")([^\:\}\,])/'),
//       vvvvvvvvv                 vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
// To remove the new lines         Replacing valid " with '
array('","', "$1'$3")
, $json);

echo $json; // {"LOGRADOURO":"Joana D'Arc","NUMERO":"257","COMPLEMENTO":"","BAIRRO":"barreiro"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array first and then replace the `"` width `'` in each entry. After that you use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). If your data comes as json, use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) first.

```
$str = array(
'LOGRADOURO'=> 'Joana D"Arc',
'NUMERO'=>'257',
'COMPLEMENTO'=>'',
'BAIRRO'=>'barreiro'
);

foreach($str as $sk => $s) {
$str[$sk] = str_replace('"', "'", $s);
}

echo json_encode($str);
```

You can also have look at [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) if you want just to prevent further errors beacuse of `"` inside the string.

Comment: I really need a preg_replace, like this:

$return = preg_replace ('/ ("+)" ("+) /'," $1"$2", $return);

Comment: Ok then I unfortunately can't help you. Regex isn't my thing :S

Comment: And my problem is in json_decode, the database that creates this json

Comment: @JorgeJúnior then maybe you should tackle the problem at DB level ? If you can manage to escape the double quote in `D"Arc` -> `D\"Arc` then you'll have a valid JSON ...

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV I think the problem is simply that the name is incorrect. But I really don't know why there are double quotes in the db.